# What permission are required to view Directory log in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

I am trying to access the Directory activity log in my Azure tenant, but I am getting the error that `I don't have permission to view Directory log`.

I am trying to figure out if anyone know the permission required to view those logs.

Also, I am trying to have the least privilege possible.

[image]

Comment: ... and the link to "learn more" tells you what?

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread and figured I would add my two cents. The Global Administrator grant all is a bad practice even if that is what worked for @Sridevi. You should always try for least privileged.

I was trying to read the Directory logs with the following PowerShell command:

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs
```

I was able to allow this by creating a Custom Role group with only the following permission:

```
microsoft.directory/auditLogs/allProperties/read
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, Azure RBAC roles under subscription won't work for accessing Directory Activity logs.

To access the Directory activity log, you need to have  **Global Administrator** role on your Azure tenant.

When I tried to access Directory activity log with user having Contributor role, I got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

To resolve the error, I assigned **Global Administrator** role to the user under Azure AD tenant like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and Administrators -> All roles -> Global Administrator*

[image]

After assigning above role, you can also check **`Assigned roles`** of the user like below:

[image]

You need to wait for **5-10 minutes** after assigning the directory role as there will be delay.

When I tried to access **Directory Activity** logs with above user after few minutes, I can see the logs successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Active Directory activity logs in Azure Monitor - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-activity-logs-azure-monitor#getting-started)

Comment: I tried the custom role but I am still not able to access the logs. Do I need more then the microsoft.directory/auditLogs/allProperties/read role?

Comment: Yes with Global Administrator it is working, but I need to follow the least privileges.